# Make OpenVPN clients accessible internally

Tags: openvpn

As far networking goes I'm a newbie, so please don't flame me .:)

I have an internal network of 192.168.1.0/24 and a VPN server on 192.168.200.1 that handles VPN clients. Each VPN client has it's own IP in 192.168.200.0/24 network. My router is on IP 192.168.1.1 and is connected to the Internet. I have configured the whole thing so that VPN clients can connect to computers in my internal network (192.168.1.0/24).

What do I have to do to allow internal computers connect to VPN clients?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ensure that the appropriate routes are setup to direct traffic to the VPN server, and that all necessary firewall rules are setup to allow that traffic to flow.  That should be all.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I know that this should be done, except that I don't know how to do it. :) What are the appropriate commands?

Comment: It depends on many things -- the OSes involved, the network topology, what configuration method you want to use...

Comment: I'm using dd-wrt on router, and openvpn server is running on Linux with 3.0.0 kernel. I'm not sure what configuration method I want to use. Can you suggest one?